# Show that function has maximum in a given interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is a question from my exam in Calculus I:

> **Problem 4**
>
> Prove or disprove:
>
> [...]
>
> a) The function $f(x) = \left(\sin(x) + \sqrt{\log(1+x^2)}\right)^3 e^{\cos(x) - 1}$ has a maximum in $[-1,3]$, but no minimum.

I know that I have to look for solutions with $f'(x) = 0 \;\land\; f''(x) < 0$. But when I try to calculate the derivative I always miscalculate and so does probably everyone else.

Is there a way to get to the result without calculating the derivative?

Comment: $f$ is continous, now use the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: Maple has found a Minimum and a Maximum

Comment: I'm sure Maple will be allowed in the next exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is well-defined and continuous in the whole closed interval $[-1, 3]$.
And it's continuous because it's a "combination" of continuous functions.
So it reaches both maximum and minimum in that interval.
As noted already by others this follows from the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).